# How to list active plugins in an SBT project?

Tags: sbt

How can I see SBT plugins loaded in a project? `tasks -V` shows `discoveredSbtPlugins` task exists, but

```
> discoveredSbtPlugins
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Dec 4, 2015 2:40:02 PM
> show discoveredSbtPlugins
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/aromanov/IdeaProjects/splinter/splinter-core/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[info] splinter-core/compile:discoveredSbtPlugins
[info]  sbt.PluginDiscovery$DiscoveredNames@37eda1fc
[info] splinter/compile:discoveredSbtPlugins
[info]  sbt.PluginDiscovery$DiscoveredNames@5225c413
```

isn't particularly useful.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try typing `plugins` in the sbt console.

```
> plugins
In file:/Users/martin/Desktop/sbt-memory/
sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin: enabled in sbt-memory
sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin: enabled in sbt-memory
sbt.plugins.CorePlugin: enabled in sbt-memory
sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin: enabled in sbt-memory
```

Comment: And is there a way to get the version of the loaded plugins ? I know they are in the plug-ins.sbt but it's for debugging purpose